# How is hidden service directory protected from DOS?

Tags: onion-services, directory

What is the maximum number of hidden services DHT (Distributed Hash Table) can hold? Who maintains the directory? What stops anyone from creating a huge list of hidden services (onion addresses) that don't really exist? I understand it is not possible to spoof them as the name is validated using public key.

Comment: What is the reason for down vote?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the maximum number of hidden services DHT (Distributed Hash Table) can hold?

Theoretically, the whole hash space.

> Who maintains the directory?

All HSDir relays.

> What stops anyone from creating a huge list of hidden services (onion addresses) that don't really exist?

Nothing.
However, HSDirs are still protected from this kind of DoS. Hidden services have entry in the DHT only when they are active. How can an attacker keep so many hidden services alive before making huge loads to the directory?

Comment: How do they know if it is active? One can spoof thousands of hidden services with just one computer

Comment: That computer has to maintain thousands of circuits and floods even more  than only the DHT - every relay has a chance to participate in these circuits.